# What to do when people want to answer a different question?

Tags: discussion

Yesterday I posted [this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/255187/99361) about names of groups of Starcraft II units. I thought I indicated clearly enough that I was referring to groups of units of a single type, where the name of the group is singular. However, the comments and the first answer to this question really want to provide definitions for SCII shorthands and slang the commentators use to refer to different unit compositions. These answers are useful, but they are answers to a different question, which I am happy to ask.

This is my first time posting in Arqade SE so I am erring on the side of caution and asking on meta first.

Question: should I:

- change my question so it fits with the current discussion?
- further clarify my question so that the peanut gallery understands what I'm asking, and create a new question about SCII jargon?
- Do something else?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Comment on the answers, indicating that they are not what you are looking for.  You can downvote them as well.  You may also want to edit the question to make it clearer what you actually want; it's perfectly OK to include a list of things you don't want (so long as that list isn't your *whole* question).

If you like, you *can* ask a new question to which the answer is appropriate, and encourage the answerer to move the answer there, but you are not obligated to do so.

Comment: Great, thanks for the quick response.